# HTML5 Application Start

Tags: html

I am going to be creating a fairly large application soon.  I want it to be an HTML5 Application, cross platform, and for mobile devices.  I also want there to be a Desktop version, and a mobile version.

What tools are there, that will help me to start creating an HTML5 application?  I am up for learning any language needed.

Can I use Joomla, as a content management system (since it is an HTML application), since it has module for authentication and other good stuff?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you researched? There are so many resources available for this question, and as it is asked, is far too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: I've looked into TideSDK, Montage, Qt, but all of them seem to have their disadvantages, either they aren't up to date, or they don't support all platforms, or its hard to ship the app out, or requires too much work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to structure an app, there are scaffolding tools such as [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/).

If you're looking for a cross platform HTML5 development platform, there is [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) as well as many others.

As for design, look into [responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) so it works anywhere. You won't get the performance of native applications on mobile devices, but it's getting better all the time.